# Exception when attempting to create the jdbc tables

Tags: amazon-aurora, akka-persistence, lagom

When connecting to Amazon RDS MySQL Aurora the lagom service throws an exception when attempting to create the jdbc tables

```
2018-01-16T00:11:32.891Z [[31merror[0m] akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy 
[sourceThread=userservice-v1-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18, akkaTimestamp=
00:11:32.877UTC, akkaSource=akka://userservice-v1/user/slickOffsetStorePrepare-singleton/singleton/slickOffsetStorePrepare, 
sourceActorSystem=userservice-v1] - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"read_side_offsets" ("read_side_id" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"tag" VARCHAR(255) NOT' at line 1 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '"read_side_offsets" ("read_side_id" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"tag" VARCHAR(255) NOT' at line 1

2018-01-16T00:11:32.896Z [[31merror[0m] akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy 
[sourceThread=userservice-v1-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20, akkaTimestamp=    
00:11:32.885UTC, akkaSource=akka://userservice-v1/user/jdbcCreateTables-singleton/singleton/jdbcCreateTables, 
sourceActorSystem=userservice-v1] - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'"journal" ("ordering" BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,"deleted" BOOLEAN DEFAULT f' 
at line 1 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"journal" ("ordering" BIGINT 
AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,"deleted" BOOLEAN DEFAULT f' at line 1
```

I haven't been able to find if this is a known issue of a configuration element that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you've selected the correct Slick driver for your database as described in the Lagom documentation on [Relational Database Persistent Entities](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/PersistentEntityRDBMS.html#Configuration):

```
jdbc-defaults.slick.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
```

Comment: Unfortunately we do have that in our configuration already. This works fine when we run the service locally against a MySQL 5.6 that is locally hosted